# GoogleMap v2 didn't appear on the device

Tags: android, maps

I make this example http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/12/google-rolls-out-android-maps-api-v2/, but didn't appear the map in my device

this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.control_guard"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
<permission
    android:name="com.control_guard.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.control_guard.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Inicio"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_inicio"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" 
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Login"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="MenuControlGuard" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="MenuPrincipal" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Asistencia" 
        android:theme="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="ListaPersonal"
        android:theme="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DatosPersonal"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_datos_personal" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListaClientes"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lista__clientes" 
        android:theme="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DatosCliente"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_datos_cliente" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuReportes"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu_reportes" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NuevoReporte"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nuevo_reporte" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Lista_Reportes"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lista__reportes"
        android:theme="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditarReporte"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_editar_reporte" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuPrincipalOperaciones"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu_principal_operaciones" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".VerReportes"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ver_reportes" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListaSupervisor"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lista_supervisor"
        android:theme="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Mapa"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mapa" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAUvGf-KcrLy4ptevrE5LRK9XCVuYf7vOE" />
</application>
```

`

My .xml is

```
   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />`
```

And this is my .java

```
package com.control_guard;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Mapa extends Activity  {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapa);

    final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
     final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    final GoogleMap map;

      map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
          .getMap();
      Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
          .title("Hamburg"));
      Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(KIEL)
          .title("Kiel")
          .snippet("Kiel is cool")
          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
              .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

      // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
      map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

      // Zoom in, animating the camera.
      map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mapa, menu);
    return true;
}`
```

Please i need help with this problem, i dont found the error in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have u gone through all the steps mentioned in the documentation. If not, just go through it once.. just few simple steps.. and u will be ready to go, and they ar really nice

Here's the link to that.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

If problem still persist then again raise your problem..

Comment: Thanks for answer,  I follow all steps but the problem persist, one diferents is in Obtaining an API Key the package is  com.example.android.mapexample and in the Android Manifest is com.example.mapdemo, the problem could is here ??

Answer (score 1):

You need an api key, yours is empty in your manifest:

```
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API-KEY" />
```

Follow [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have API key: android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyAUvGf-KcrLy4ptevrE5LRK9XCVuYf7vOE"

Comment: I dont know why dont show in my manifest, some another problem in my code?

Comment: Can you update your question with your latest code and manifest?

Comment: Your updated xml and code seems ok. Have you registered your api key with the com.control_guard package? Also, are you installing the generated apk to the device from the computer you obtained the SHA-1 key from?

Comment: yes, i registered with com.control_guard and generated apk from computer where obtained SHA-1 key, but in this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start,the register have .android in the package and the permisson dont'n have .android, also i run the app over nexus 4 with version 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

you need an API key to show google maps in your application. please visit this site and create API key and put API key in your android manifest file.
       https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey